# Multi table deletion MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a simple database to use as a mock example for an E-Commerce website.  One things that I am required to do it delete records from the database using PHP.  I can delete a user name or a order or etc.. But when I try to do them all at once I am screwing something up.  What I want to happen is delete all the information about a user. Example : User info, Shipping Info, Billing Info, Credit Card Info, and anything else to do with the specific user.  My tables are as followed.

```
mysql> SHOW columns FROM shirt_billing_addresses; 
 +----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | shirt_billing_addresses_id | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
 | house                      | mediumint(9) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
 | street                     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
 | city                       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
 | state                      | char(2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
 | zip                        | char(5)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
 +----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

 mysql> SHOW columns FROM shirt_credit_cards; 
 +-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | shirt_credit_cards_id | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
 | shirt_users_id        | mediumint(9) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
 | type                  | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
 | no                    | char(16)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
 | security_code         | char(3)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
 +-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 5 rows in set (0.04 sec)

 mysql> SHOW columns FROM shirt_orders; 
 +-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field                       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | shirt_orders_id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment  
 | order_total                 | double(6,2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | payment_date                | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | shirt_credit_cards_id       | mediumint(9) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
 | shirt_shipping_addresses_id | mediumint(9) | NO   | MUL | NULL                    
 | shirt_billing_addresses_id  | mediumint(9) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                
 | shirt_shipping_methods_id   | tinyint(4)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 7 rows in set (0.02 sec)

 mysql> SHOW columns FROM shirt_shipping_addresses; 
 +-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field                       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | shirt_shipping_addresses_id | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment  
| house                       | mediumint(9) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| street                      | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| city                        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| state                       | char(2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| zip                         | char(5)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SHOW columns FROM shirt_users; 
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| shirt_users_id | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| first_name     | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| last_name      | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| email          | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| user_id        | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| password       | char(40)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SHOW columns FROM shirt_users_types;         
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| shirt_users_types_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| shirt_users_id       | mediumint(9) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| shirt_types_id       | smallint(6)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| shirt_orders_id      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| type_quantity        | smallint(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| type_total           | double(6,2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

The PHP code I have is as follows:

```
@mysqli_query($link, "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
    $select_sui = "SELECT 
    shirt_users.shirt_users_id, 
    shirt_users_types.shirt_users_types_id, 
    shirt_orders.shirt_orders_id, 
    shirt_shipping_addresses.shirt_shipping_addresses_id, 
    shirt_billing_addresses.shirt_billing_addresses_id, 
    shirt_credit_cards.shirt_credit_cards_id 
    from
    shirt_users, 
    shirt_users_types, 
    shirt_orders, 
    shirt_shipping_addresses, 
    shirt_billing_addresses, 
    shirt_credit_cards
    where
    shirt_users.shirt_users_id = shirt_users_types.shirt_users_id and
    shirt_users_types.shirt_orders_id = shirt_orders.shirt_orders_id and
    shirt_orders.shirt_shipping_addresses_id = shirt_shipping_addresses.shirt_shipping_addresses_id and
    shirt_orders.shirt_billing_addresses_id = shirt_billing_addresses.shirt_billing_addresses_id and
    shirt_orders.shirt_credit_cards_id = shirt_credit_cards.shirt_credit_cards_id and
    shirt_users.shirt_users_id = $shirt_users_id";
```

The only problem is that this query will return an empty set unless all the tables have the correct information in it.  This is a problem because if a user has not ordered any items yet but I want to delete them from the database, It will not allow me.  Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: fyi: You can replace `SHOW columns FROM shirt_billing_addresses;` with `desc shirt_billing_addresses;`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `LEFT JOIN` to link your tables ([MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/join.html)).

```
SELECT [...]
    FROM shirt_users 
    LEFT JOIN shirt_users_types ON shirt_users.shirt_users_id = shirt_users_types.shirt_users_id
    LEFT JOIN shirt_orders ON shirt_users_types.shirt_orders_id = shirt_orders.shirt_orders_id
    LEFT JOIN shirt_shipping_addresses ON shirt_orders.shirt_shipping_addresses_id = shirt_shipping_addresses.shirt_shipping_addresses_id
    LEFT JOIN shirt_billing_addresses ON shirt_orders.shirt_billing_addresses_id = shirt_billing_addresses.shirt_billing_addresses_id
    LEFT JOIN shirt_credit_cards ON shirt_orders.shirt_credit_cards_id = shirt_credit_cards.shirt_credit_cards_id
    WHERE
    shirt_users.shirt_users_id = $shirt_users_id
```

With this you'll be able to load `shirt_users` even if there is no linked record in other tables.

**EDIT for Delete records**

If you want to delete in all your tables in only one request, you must use as syntax which is fairly the same as your first try (by replacing the `SELECT` statement by `DELETE`). ANd you will get the same problem (it will only delete records which have a linked record in each table and not null).

**Method 1 :**

***NB : Your DB must support foreign keys (for example, MyISAM doesn't support it but InnoDB does).***

You can use this method, if you always need in your app to delete all linked records.

The most beautiful way to achieve this is to add a `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint on your relations :

```
-- Drop the old constraint ("fk_test" must be replace by your constraint name)
ALTER TABLE shirt_users_types DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_test`;

-- Create the new with ON DELETE
ALTER TABLE shirt_users_types
   ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_test`
   FOREIGN KEY (`shirt_users_id` )
   REFERENCES `shirt_users` (`shirt_users_id` )
   ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

When you will delete a `shirt_users` entry, all linked records in `shirt_users_types`.

In a few words, with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, each time you will delete a parent element (the `One` side of the relation), all the children (the `Many` side of the relation or the table wich contains the column `<related_record>_id`) will be automatically deleted too.

**Method 2 :**

If your relation can be nullable (for example if `shirt_users_types.shirt_orders_id` can be null) or if your DB schema not permits to delete all needed records with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

You can delete your records with several `DELETE` using relations to `shirt_users` in order to retrieve records in each linked table. (For correct syntax of `DELETE` with relations see [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)).

In your code your unique identifier is `$shirt_users_id`, so you have to start by deleting in the tables which are not directly linked to `shirt_users` and by reaching back your relations to finish by the table `shirt_users`.

If you don't delete records in the correct order, you will not be able to delete all you need.

For example, with schema described in your question, if you delete records in `shirt_orders` before `shirt_shipping_addresses`, you will no longer can retrieve shipping addresses with `$shirt_users_id` because `shirt_shipping_addresses` is linked to `shirt_users` due to its relation with `shirt_orders`.

So the correct order for your current schema is (there is no need to have an order for table on the same line the list above) :

- shirt_shipping_addresses / shirt_billing_addresses
- shirt_orders / shirt_credit_cards / shirt_users_types
- shirt_users

You can have a `contraint fails` error due to foreign keys. In this case you can make your delete in a `TRANSACTION` (it's a best practice) or disable foreign key checks for your queries.

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, this now allows me to retrieve them records, but still not delete them but this is VERY helpful and id assume going to point me in the right direction!

Comment: @NerdsRaisedHand : I have edited my post to add more information about deleting. Hope it will help.